# Python question about constructor and match statement

Tags: python

I'm learning Python using the [tutorial on the official website](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#patterns-and-classes) and I came across an interesting example that I couldn't quite parse.

```
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int

def where_is(point):
    match point:
        case Point(x=0, y=0):
            print("Origin")
        case Point(x=0, y=y):
            print(f"Y={y}")
        case Point(x=x, y=0):
            print(f"X={x}")
        case Point():
            print("Somewhere else")
        case _:
            print("Not a point")
```

In a previous example, it mentions that point is an (x, y) tuple but I don't know if it applies to this example. In any case, I don't quite understand how the function where_is is supposed to work. I've tried this example by putting in a tuple into the argument for where_is, but all it will return is the last case: Not a point. I've tried placing "Point()" into the argument, and that does return "Somewhere else", although that still doesn't explain how the first 3 cases are supposed to work. I've had success with it returning Origin, Y = whatever, or X = whatever2 if I change the class Point to read x = 0, y= 0, or x = 0, y = whatever, or x = whatever2, y = 0.

```
def where_is(point):
    match point:
        case Point(x=0, y=0):
            print("Origin")
        case Point(x=0, y=y):
            print(f"Y={y}")
        case Point(x=x, y=0):
            print(f"X={x}")
        case Point():
            print("Somewhere else")
        case _:
            print("Not a point")

class Point:
    x=0
    y=0

>>> where_is(Point())
    Origin

class Point:
    x=1
    y=0

>>> where_is(Point())
    X=1

class Point:
    x=0
    y=1

>>> where_is(Point())
    Y=1
```

However, coming from a C++ background, I'm not sure if this is what the example is even trying to show, and if it is, why I can match x or y to random values in such a manner.

The tutorial then goes on to say: "You can use positional parameters with some builtin classes that provide an ordering for their attributes (e.g. dataclasses). You can also define a specific position for attributes in patterns by setting the **match_args** special attribute in your classes. If it’s set to (“x”, “y”), the following patterns are all equivalent (and all bind the y attribute to the var variable):"

```
Point(1, var)
Point(1, y=var)
Point(x=1, y=var)
Point(y=var, x=1)
```

And I have no idea what it's trying to say. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _"In a previous example, it mentions that point is an (x, y) tuple but I don't know if it applies to this example"_. It doesn't in the second example. It's not a great example IMO, since it doesn't show any code that actually assigns the `x` and `y` attributes of a `Point` instance. The type hints (e.g. `x: int`) aren't actually relevant, and are only include to hint (no pun intended) about what attributes would be assigned behind the curtain. The body of `Point`'s definition could just be a `pass` statement.

Comment: Looks like the `Point` class is incomplete. I guess they left out the code for the class for brevity ??

Comment: Do note that in your second snippet, you're swapping attributes of `Point` instances (what's hinted in the tutorial example), with class attributes of the `Point` type itself. This still "works" since attribute lookup does default to looking up attributes of the object's type, but it isn't a good of typical usage.

Comment: Mentally supply a `@dataclass` decorator to the definition of `Point`, and it will work.

Comment: @001 Thats what I figured as well, since they don't provide any constructors.

Answer (score 3):

The `match` statement you're asking about is a fairly new feature in Python. It was added in Python 3.10, and introduced in three PEPs, [634](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/) (which gives a more formal specification of the syntax), [635](https://peps.python.org/pep-0635/) (which describes the motivation for the feature), and [636](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/) (which is a tutorial, and likely the template for the documentation you were reading).

While a `match` looks a bit like a `switch` statement from C++, it has some important differences. Each `case` statement uses a special matching syntax that can describe class instances in a compact way. The value given in the `match` statement is checked to see if it matches each of the `case` clauses one by one, like a chain of `if`/`elif` conditions.

Your question looks to mostly be about the case syntax, which is a bit surprising if you don't know what it's doing. By "calling" a class in the `case`, you're asking to match only instances of that class. Thus `case Point()` matches any point object (that hasn't already been matched by a previous `case` clause).

The "arguments" to the `Point` in the case statement aren't real arguments being passed to a real call to construct an instance of the class. Rather, it's fancy syntax for matching attributes. A statement like `case Point(x=0, y=0)` is equivalent to `if isinstance(obj, Point) and obj.x == 0 and obj.y == 0`. If the argument has unbound names in it, like the `y=y` example, then the conditional part of the match is followed by an assignment, `y = obj.y` (the name on the left side of the assignment is weirdly the right side of the argument in the `case` statement).

The example is made a bit more confusing than necessary by the fact that the classes being defined don't have any constructors, the attributes are hard-coded class variables. Adding a `@dataclass` decorator would make them a lot more logical, that's the whole idea behind equating constructor arguments with attributes.

Comment: It's not really like `switch`, which is more like a computed `goto`. A `match` statement is closer to a `if-elif` statement , with each condition being checked in sequence. The key difference is that instead of explicit boolean expressions, each condition is pattern-matching construct.

Comment: @chepner thanks for that correction. I've edited to, I hope, give a more accurate description (as well as pointing to the right PEPs, I had one that was superseded in my list initially).

Answer (score 2):

That example makes no sense as written, because they didn't decorate the class with a `dataclasses` decorator, so you can't construct individual `Point` instances with different values in any convenient manner (`p = Point()`, `p.x = 1`, `p.y = 2` is an option, but it defeats the point of having classes if you don't have an initializer to establish the attributes on construction).

If you just add the necessary decorator though, and `dataclass` will generate an initializer for you:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Point:
    # Rest of code unchanged
```

Then you can demonstrate how this example is supposed to work with *different* `Point` objects by just doing:

```
>>> where_is(Point(1,2))
Somewhere else

>>> where_is(Point(0,2))
Y=2
```

That makes it actually useful; you might collect an arbitrary number of `Point`s (not just make replacement versions of the *class*), and the `match` will work with them trivially.

Answer (score 2):

Each `case` clause uses something that *looks* like an object construction, but it's just syntax used to match an object of type `Point` with various *values* for their `x` and `y` attributes.

First, start with a complete example of `Point` that will work.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int
```

Now you'll call `where_is` with an appropriately constructed object:

```
>>> where_is(Point(0, 0))
Origin
>>> where_is(Point(9, 0))
X=9
>>> where_is((3, 5))
Not a point
```

`Point` is a tuple in the *mathematical* sense, namely an "ordered" (or at least discriminated) pair of values. An instance of `Point` is not an instance of the Python type `tuple`.

`Point(x=0, y=0)` as a *class pattern* only matches `Point` instances whose `x` attribute is 0 and `y` attribute is 0. Note it doesn't really matter how the object was *created*, and `x` and `y` refer directly to instance attributes, not necessarily keyword arguments used by `__init__`.

`match_args` basically provides a "mapping" of positions to attribute names. Consider this definition of `Point`:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Now, an attempt to match against `Point(0, 0)` rather than `Point(x=0, y=0)` would fail, because the `match` statement doesn't know which positional argument in the pattern corresponds to which argument. Defining `match_args = ("x", "y")` explicitly pairs the 0th positional argument to the attribute `x` and the 1th argument to `y`, which would let you write

def where_is(point):
match point:
case Point(0, 0):
print("Origin")
case Point(0, y):
print(f"Y={y}")
case Point(x, 0):
print(f"X={x}")
case Point():
print("Somewhere else")
case _:
print("Not a point")

Note that one of the things the `@dataclass` constructor does is set `__match_args__` for you based on the defined fields.

```
>>> @dataclass
... class Point:
...   x: int
...   y: int
...
>>> Point.__match_args__
('x', 'y')
```